# scrlttr2 positioning - signature business title and name in same line

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

I am using `scrlttr2` class of the KOMA-Script package and would like to have business title and name on the same line, with left-aligned title and right-aligned name, like shown at the picture.

[image: Imgur]

I've made some trick with `\hspace` and set of length commands (see MWE below):

```
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\signedby}{John Dow}
\newcommand{\signedtitle}{CEO}
\newlength{\signedbylength}
\setlength{\signedbylength}{\textwidth-\widthof{\signedtitle}-\widthof{\signedby}}
\setkomavar{signature}{\signedtitle\hspace{\signedbylength}\signedby}
```

It works, but I am afraid that this is workaround and it can be done in  some more elegant way?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, backaddress=off, 14pt, refline=nodate]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{mweletter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% some trick
\newcommand{\signedby}{John Dow}
\newcommand{\signedtitle}{CEO}
\newlength{\signedbylength}
\setlength{\signedbylength}{%
    \textwidth-\widthof{\signedtitle}-\widthof{\signedby}}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Temporary Solutions, Inc.}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{%
\textsf{\href{mailto:inbox@solutions.org}{inbox@solutions.org}}}
\setkomavar{signature}{\signedtitle\hspace{\signedbylength}\signedby}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Ministry of Health\\
05000 Somewhere, Baker St., 7\\
\textsf{\href{mailto:inbox@mh.gov}{inbox@mh.gov}}}

\opening{}
\begin{center}
\normalfont\bfseries REQUEST\\
for information \normalfont
\end{center}\bigskip

\lipsum[1]

\noindent\closing{Sincerely,}
\noindent\today
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The `mweletter` package source:

```
% mweletter.sty
\ProvidesFile{mweletter.lco}
                        [2017/08/25 letter class option]
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[%
    a4paper,pdftex,left=30mm,right=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm%
    ]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{cmap}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{indentfirst}
\RequirePackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[protrusion=true]{microtype} % Висячая пунктуация
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage[unicode, colorlinks, pdfstartview=FitH, pdflang=UK]{hyperref}
\@setplength{toaddrvpos}{10mm}
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{120mm}
\@setplength{toaddrheight}{0mm}
\@setplength{backaddrheight}{0pt}
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{30mm}
\@setplength{firstheadhpos}{120mm}
\@setplength{refvpos}{70mm} % 110
\@setplength{subjectaftervskip}{\baselineskip}
\@setplength{backaddrheight}{10mm}
\setkomavar{date}{\flushleft\vspace{-\baselineskip}\today\par}
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{8mm}
\newcommand{\rom}[1]{%
  \textup{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}%
}
\renewcommand\raggedsignature{}
\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0mm}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can patch `\closing` to add the usage of a new variable:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mweletter.sty}
\ProvidesFile{mweletter.lco}
                        [2017/08/25 letter class option]
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[%
    a4paper,pdftex,left=30mm,right=15mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm%
    ]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{cmap}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage{indentfirst}
\RequirePackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[protrusion=true]{microtype} % Висячая пунктуация
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage[unicode, colorlinks, pdfstartview=FitH, pdflang=UK]{hyperref}
\@setplength{toaddrvpos}{10mm}
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{120mm}
\@setplength{toaddrheight}{0mm}
\@setplength{backaddrheight}{0pt}
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{30mm}
\@setplength{firstheadhpos}{120mm}
\@setplength{refvpos}{70mm} % 110
\@setplength{subjectaftervskip}{\baselineskip}
\@setplength{backaddrheight}{10mm}
\setkomavar{date}{\flushleft\vspace{-\baselineskip}\today\par}
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{8mm}
\newcommand{\rom}[1]{%
  \textup{\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}}%
}
\renewcommand\raggedsignature{}
\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0mm}
\newkomavar{position}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\closing{\usekomavar{signature}}{\usekomavar{position}}{}{\failure}
\xpatchcmd\closing{\usekomavar{signature}}{\usekomavar{position}}{}{\failure}
\xpatchcmd\closing{\parbox}{\parbox[b]}{}{\failure}
\xpatchcmd\closing{\par}{\xpar}{}{\failure}
\xpatchcmd\closing{\par}{\hfill\strut\usekomavar{signature}\par}{}{\failure}
\xpatchcmd\closing{\xpar}{\par}{}{\failure}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[paper=a4, backaddress=off, 14pt, refline=nodate]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{mweletter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% some trick
\setkomavar{fromname}{Temporary Solutions, Inc.}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{%
\textsf{\href{mailto:inbox@solutions.org}{inbox@solutions.org}}}
\setkomavar{signature}{John Dow}
\setkomavar{position}{CEO}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Ministry of Health\\
05000 Somewhere, Baker St., 7\\
\textsf{\href{mailto:inbox@mh.gov}{inbox@mh.gov}}}

\opening{}
\begin{center}
\normalfont\bfseries REQUEST\\
for information \normalfont
\end{center}\bigskip

\lipsum[1]

\noindent\closing{Sincerely,}
\noindent\today
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But this does not work, if the signature has more than one line. In this case you have to encapsulate `\usekomavar{signature}` in a `tabular`, [`varwidth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) or `\parbox`.